# django admin - how to import data from spreadsheet

Tags: python, django

I thinking about how I could import data from a spreadsheet but without typing it all out, I was thinking of import the file itself that will automatically import the data to the right columns.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Django CSV Import](https://github.com/edcrewe/django-csvimport), it have Admin interface import.

Answer (score 0):

this library is working nice - unless you looking 10k records to load from xls
https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export